# Rails multiple belongs_to assignment

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, belongs-to

Given

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :discussions
   has_many :posts
end
```

Discussions:

```
class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :posts
end
```

Posts:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :discussion 
end
```

I am currently initializing Posts in the controller via

```
@post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
```

My question is, how do I set/save/edit the @post model such that the relationship between the post and the discussion is also set?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Save and edit discussions along with post

**Existing Discussion**

To associate the post you're building with an existing discussion, just merge the id into the post params

```
@post = current_user.posts.build(
          params[:post].merge(
            :discussion_id => existing_discussion.id
        )
```

You will have to have a hidden input for discussion id in the form for `@post` so the association gets saved.

**New Discussion**

If you want to build a **new discussion** along with every post and manage its attributes via the form, use [`accepts_nested_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for)

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :discussion
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :discussion
end
```

You then have to build the discussion in the controller with `build_discussion` after you built the post

```
@post.build_discussion
```

And in your form, you can include nested fields for discussions

```
form_for @post do |f|
  f.fields_for :discussion do |df|
    ...etc
```

This will create a discussion along with the post. For more on nested attributes, [watch this excellent railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

### Better Relations

Furthermore, you can use the `:through` option of the [`has_many` association](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) for a more consistent relational setup:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :discussions, :through => :posts, :source => :discussion
end

class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :discussion 
end
```

Like this, the relation of the user to the discussion is maintained only in the `Post` model, and not in two places.

Comment: Wow, that was a great read. Thanks for your time.

I do have one question though.

Every time the user starts a discussion they will have to have a post, however the reverse is not necessarily true.

As in my case where a Discussion consists of many posts, would it be appropriate to flip what you said about posts and discussions such that the Discussions accepts nested attributes for posts, then do a @discussion.build_post, or is there some inconsistency that will come with that?

Comment: You're welcome. And yes, if the relationship is User has many Discussions has many Posts, then you should reflect it that way in your code.

Comment: by the way... are you familiar with the belongs_to polymorphic: true element?

Comment: Yeah, its up a bit of a different alley but still related. As with the prior code, discussions also has a belongs_to polymorphic: true. This is because a "Discussion" in my case is a general forum thread, and thus I would like to put it on other models. However the discussion would only be directly related to one of those at a time. In such a case would I still be fine using the accepts_nested_attributes_for and then building the discussion on those models? Or would you suggest another approach?

Comment: [You may have to change some code if you want to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on the polymorphic association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969025/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-belongs-to-polymorphic), but it should work fine. Since there's no other approach to polymorphic associations than to use polymorphism :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14081/discussion-between-james-pleasant-and-beat-richartz)

Comment: Do i have to make discussion_id attr_accessible in order to user this method? If that is the case, is there a way to do this without making it accessible?